# asp.net client routing with page.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, routes, single-page-application

I am trying to build a simple asp.net application (webforms) and I would like to do the routing in the client. This is a SPA.

I am using the page.js library to handle the routing. My development environment is visual studio 2015 Enterprise. This is an example of a routing

```
page('/admin', display_admin);
page('/items/:sub/:id', display_item);
```

In the server-side, I setup things so that for every url request, index.html is loaded (since routing is handled in the client) and the appropriate route handler is called and executed. In the web.config I have:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
      <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

see this article [ASP.NET 5 and AngularJS Part 3, Adding Client Routing](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/16/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-3-adding-client-routing)

Everything works fine when the custom url is of this form '/xxx' for example '/admin' , '/items' etc... But it does not work for complex url where the path of the form '/xxx/yyy/zzz'. ex: 'items/cars/10'. In visual studio during debug the application craches:

[image]

You can see that the server (embedded webserver in visual studio) tries to  load resources for page "1" from the folder at 'localhost:port/items/c/' which of course does not exist. This request does not reach my server where a redirect would occur to page 'index.html'.

How can I implement client-side routing in asp.net (with .html files, not .aspx files) and with complex url path?

I am guessing that this is problem related to the embedded webserver in visual studio (which is a light iis version...)

Any help, any hint would be greatly appreciated

Thank you stackoverflow community

Comment: You do use absolute paths with scripts?

Comment: This is the page.js works. It tries to mimic the behavior of express.js but in the client

Comment: So you didn't write a reference for bootstrap in index.html

Comment: The reference is there. The first time the application starts, with index.html, everything works ok. index.html is displayed. Then I enter a custom url ( matching a routing entry e.g /item/:cat/:id (for test purpose) then it looks like the browser reloads the page and then resources are messed up...But if the url has only on level (example '/item') I have no problem

Comment: So is it with *absolute* or *relative* path? I assume relative, so the browser will just try to get everything on that path. Use `/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Thank you very match. Yes it is working with absolute path. My routing is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using *relative* paths to scripts. This means the browser will assume the page being served is under `/something/else/entirely` and will ask for it there. Use an *absolute* path as `/bootstrap.min.js` to make sure it's requested properly.

The server may internally redirect to `/index.html` with your configuration but the browser doesn't know that.

The reason why single level `/something` works is due to browser still assuming everything is on the root level. An additional slash and the context moves down one "folder."